# Constrain only some elements of the variable to be integer

Tags: python, optimization, cvxpy

I have a CVXPY optimization script, with a variable made of 14 elements. The first 2 need be integer, the other 12 don't.

The [CVXPY documentation](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/advanced/index.html#attributes) says:

> *integer (bool or list of tuple) – Is the variable integer? The semantics are the same as the boolean argument.*

For the boolean attribute, they say:

> *boolean (bool or list of tuple) – Is the variable boolean (i.e., 0 or 1)? True, which constrains the entire variable to be boolean, False,
> or a list of indices which should be constrained as boolean, where
> each index is a tuple of length exactly equal to the length of shape.*

If I use the following (forcing all elements to be integer) the script works flawlessy:

```
opt_contracts = cp.Variable(14, integer=True)
```

But if I try the following:

```
opt_contracts = cp.Variable(14, integer=[0,1])
```

I get the follwing TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable.
What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I got it:

```
opt_contracts = cp.Variable(N, integer=[[0],[1]])
```